# Why is my loopback interface losing its address sporadically?

Tags: network-interface, networkmanager, ifconfig, loopback

After I upgraded to Fedora Linux 36 from 34 (first to 35) I'm getting an issue I had not faced before. The `lo` interface is losing its inet address and that's causing issues with programs that make heavy use of internal networking like IntelliJ Idea. This is what it looks like right now

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 945854  bytes 68873995 (65.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 945854  bytes 68873995 (65.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If I run `sudo ifconfig lo down && sudo ifconfig lo up` then `lo` gets its address back but if I hibernate the laptop it loses the address again and programs start to crash and not work correctly. Also, after restarting the interface I need to restart the `docker` service too otherwise I can't access the containers normally. Anyways, I'm not sure why this started happening but I want to fix it, any ideas why it might be happening? Please let me know if you need me to provide more details.

Comment: `I'm not sure why this started happening` - did it start `After I upgraded to Fedora Linux 36 from 34`?

Comment: This can't be happening on its own, so it looks like some application/service/daemon is doing that. Which and why? I've no idea.

Comment: @JaromandaX don't be cute. The fact it happened after I upgraded doesn't mean I know WHY it started happening.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I think I found what might be the issue. I had some systemd nfs and samba auto/mounts that might have been triggering this. Those were old mounts that never gave me this issue before the upgrade, I stopped them and disabled them and after I restarted my system the issue hasn't cropped up again _yet,_ although it kept happening before I restarted the computer even though the mounts had been disabled and stopped.

Comment: @AspiringDev - I wasn't being *cute* - I left out a word .... immediately ... sorry for your confusion